# RTP unreachable SIP Phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, sip, rtp, sip-server

I try to create sip phone application on android and I have some problem which is the RTP packet is unreachable to android emulator.

I'm not sure about this problem because of IP emulator.
I can do SIP Register and can call to other soft phone but when I talk there is no audio.
After I try to capture the packet, I see that the server cannot send RTP packet to the android emulator. So, it makes my program cannot have audio.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done capture from start of call?
Have you seen no packet sent by server from start of call?

If server not sent single packet then you must check SDP parameters like,
a=sendrecv
connection ip
port of RTP

Also check that you (client) and server both are in same network.
If both are not in same network then NAT may affect RTP flow.